# How to add custom navigation sidebar in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create a tutorial site like https://www.runoob.com/ by using wordpress. I want to create some pages, for example /java , and some subpages, for example /java/java-tutorial and /java/java-intro .

I want to show a navigation sidebar in each of these subpages. I want the sidebar list all links of the subpages. How to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a Navigation Menu to Sidebar in WordPress
You can easily add navigation menu in your WordPress website using the WordPress dashboard. Login to your WordPress website and go to dashboard then-

- Go to Appearance > Widgets
- Under available widget area find your navigation menu you want to add.
- Drag and drop the menu into main sidebar widgets area
- Add a name of the menu and select from the drop-down where you want to use it.

Create a custom sidebar for WordPress website
There are a lots of plugins available for custom sidebar navigation menu. Here in this tutorial we are using Custom Sidebars — Dynamic Widget Area Manager plugin to create our custom sidebar for specific pages. This plugin offers you so many customization options. With the help of this plugins you can create multiple sidebar for multiple pages.

Download this plugin from WordPress plugin page and activate it. after activating the plugin go to your dashboard and then **Appearance > Widgets**. If the plugin is running successfully then you will able to see the option Create a new sidebar

From this page you can choose a name of your sidebar and add some description about it. If you want to create multiple sidebar then you should give a related name for each sidebar so that you can easily understand that which sidebar for which purpose. You can see all of your sidebar in **custom sidebar** section

Now from the **Available Widgets** area you need to drag and drop element you want to display in your sidebar.

For better understanding you can follow this [article](https://niamrox.com/how-to-add-a-navigation-menu-to-sidebar-in-wordpress/)